# Differential equation for rate of decay: $\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{8}{3}x$

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I need support and clarification for my working out of this differential equation.

I must solve the following, giving $x$ in terms of $t$.

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-\frac{8}{3}x$$

My approach: Divide both sides by $x$ and multiply both sides by $dt$, then integrate:

1. $\int \frac{dx}{x}=-\frac{8}{3}\int dt$
2. $\ln(x)  = -\frac{8}{3}t$

Then multiply both sides by natural log

$$x = e^{-\frac{8}{3}t}$$

Given that $x = 30$ when $t = 0$, find the rate of decay of any given substance ($x$ = substance) from $30$ to $10$, to the nearest minute. How do I calculate this?

Comment: You forgot about the constant of integration. You can calculate it from the initial conditions, $f(0)=30$. And then you just need to solve for $t$ in $f(t)=10$

Comment: It doesn't make sense to say "multiply both sides by natural log."

Comment: You don't *multiply* both sides by natural logarithm, you *apply* natural logarithm. You also forgot the constant of integration, the final result should be $x(t)=ce^{-8t/3}$ with $c=x(0)$.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=-\frac{8}{3}\to \log x(t)=-\frac{8}{3}t+C$$
$$x(t)=\exp\left({-\frac{8}{3}t+C}\right)$$
as for $t=0$ we have $x=30$ substitute and get
$30=e^C\to C = \log 30$.

So the solution is
$$x(t)=30 e^{-\frac{8 t}{3}}$$
To find when the substance $x$ goes to $10$ we must solve
$$30 e^{-\frac{8 t}{3}}=10$$
$$e^{-\frac{8 t}{3}}=\frac{1}{3}$$
$$-\frac{8 t}{3}=\log\frac{1}{3}\to t=\frac{3 \log 3}{8}\approx 0.41$$
It $t$ is in hours then the time is $25$ minutes.